# What number must be subtracted from the denominator of $\frac{10}{23}$ to make the result $\frac13$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it $\frac{10}{23} - \frac{1}x = \frac13$ or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{10}{23-x}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{10}{23-(-7)}=\frac{10}{30}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=-7$, then $\frac{10}{(23-(-7))} = \frac{10}{30} = \frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Given that $\frac{10}{23} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{3}$ then multiply both sides by $3 \cdot 23 \cdot x$ to obtain $3\cdot 10 \cdot x - 3 \cdot 23 = 23 \cdot x$ which becomes $x = \frac{69}{7}$. This can be seen in the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{10}{23} - \frac{1}{x} &= \frac{10}{23} - \frac{7}{69} = \frac{30}{69} - \frac{7}{69} = \frac{23}{3 \cdot 23} = \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

Comment: The OP didnt set up the problem correctly.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The descriptive words did not match the equation provided, but in view of the equation an alternate method has been shown. What this really shows is one irreducible fraction minus another irreducible fraction yields another fraction.